# Recursive hailstone sequence (Python 3.x) to return a flat list

Tags: python-3.x, recursion

My first post on here, I'm a beginner programmer who enjoys coding in spare time. Apologies in advance for any possible, obvious (to you) errors in logic / comprehension.

I'm just trying to grasp recursion. Understand the structure, the rationale for base case etc, some difficulty with grasping the whole 'unwinding' process.

I'm doing some exercises to improve.

I'm now working on Hailstone Sequence. My function is fine generating the numbers (unless the initial input n = 1, but that's a minor problem at this stage) but it is supposed to return a flat list, and the best I can get is a multidimensional array.

I would like to (if possible) avoid writing a separate function or any code outside of the Hailstone function which proceeds to 'flatten' the list.

My code so far. Please help!

```
def hailstone(n):
  if n ==1:
    return n
  else:
    if n%2 == 0:
      return [n] + [hailstone(n//2)]
    else:
      return [n] + [hailstone(3*n+1)]

n = int(input())
print(hailstone(n))
```

Comment: Your code indentation is incorrect on the first else: block

Comment: Thanks! Amended now.

Answer (score 1):

Output from your program

```
print(hailstone(5))
# [5, [16, [8, [4, [2, 1]]]]]
```

Expected output

```
print(hailstone(5))
# [5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]
```

Your program is good and close to the expected result. The problem is, in your recursive calls to `hailstone`, you are wrapping the result in `[]`.
 Instead, always return `[n]` and optionally concatenate the additional terms in the sequence

```
def hailstone(n):
  if n ==1:
    return [n] # always wrap n in []
  else:
    if n%2 == 0:
      return [n] + [hailstone(n//2)] # do not wrap here
    else:
      return [n] + [hailstone(3*n+1)] # do not wrap here
```

The if/else->if/else would normally be written using `elif` instead

```
def hailstone(n):
  if n == 1:
    return [n]
  elif n % 2 == 0:
    return [n] + hailstone (n // 2)
  else:
    return [n] + hailstone (3 * n + 1)

print (hailstone (5))
# [5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]
```

To get an understanding for how this works, we look at `hailstone` and notice each of the `return` branches...

1. Each branch *always* returns a list
2. In the two recursive branches, we return a list *plus* the result of the recursive call
3. Since we know that `hailstone` always returns a list, we know that `[n] + hailstone(...)` will always be a valid result

Comment: Thanks so much for this, works perfectly and you've explained it well.